# A module to watch active users and possible send them messages directly

Tags: 7, users

As I develop an online store, I have debugging logs tracking site activity. the Ubercart based store has one department open, and 5 more under construction, so we have customers showing up and browsing. Every once in a while, like right now as a matter of fact, there is someone from an IP address (current one is internal to Bandai corporation in Japan) hitting every single product page on the site, and adding every product to their cart. I don't know what they are up to, but I'd like to show them a CAPTCHA.

Examining logs, about once a week some IP address from Japan, Korea, Russia, or China seems to comb the entire site. And I don't think these are search engines, because our products don't appear when I search for them in the various search engines. (We've not submitted the site yet, nor are any site maps for the search engines made yet.)

Does anyone know if there is a module that would allow me to watch the active users, and check their activity before presenting a CAPTCHA?

Comment: I take those users are not logged-in.